# Getting result from SQL Server Stored Procedure

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, data-integration, pentaho-data-integration

I need to get the result from a stored procedure in a MSSQL Server database. I tried different ways:

1. Using a Table Input Step, with this query: `exec dbo.storedproc @param1 = 5, @param2 = 12, @param3 = null, @param4 = null, @param5 = '2017/08/29', @param6 = 1`. When I right click on it -> Show output fields, it shows me the output fields from the stored procedure, but I don't know how to get the results and dump them into another table.
2. Using the Call DB Procedure step. With this one, I set up the input parameters, and tried to pass them through a Generate Rows step. But, With this one I don't even get the output parameters.

Please help me figure out how to do this.
With regards,

Comment: What happens if you connect your `Table input` step directly to a `Table output` step, and then connect the output step to your target table?

Comment: @Brian.D.Myers, I did that, the table output step creates the table with all the fields, but the table doesn't get any data. I'm using a large stored procedure, and haven't been able to convert it into a table-valued function. Any ideas? Thanks for the quick response, I suffered a delay because of a hurricane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Brian.D.Myers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1515537/brian-d-myers) suggested, the best approach is execute the stored procedure in a `Table input` step, and connect it to a `Table output` step. That, alongside the fact that the stored procedure must be executed with the following syntax: `exec stored_procedure_name [@param = value,]`

Thanks a lot!